# How to add collision detection in a 2D car game in XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0

Right, I'm making a 2d car racing game. So far I've got the car moving etc (with a little help of course) and was wondering how do I go about adding collision detection in XNA. I've taken a bumper part (from the whole track), and made it as a separate .png file. And I was thinking of adding a collision detection box around it (so if 'car' hits 'bumper' move back by so and so). How do I add collison detection to the bumper, and integrate it with the car? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial:  http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel

Source code for the tutorial is in Downloads, under the two (ugly) blue boxes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this would be a lot easier if the cars were always straight--not rotated. If they were rotated you wouldn't be able to use rectangles to help.
If you do, then you could instead have the bumper included in car.png. 
Then you could use the coordinates of the car and add certain values to get the length and width of the region for the bumper. 
You can then do

```
Rectangle bumperBoundingBox = new Rectangle
(
    (int)X_COORDINATE_OF_CAR, 
    (int)Y_COORDINATE_OF_CAR, 
    (int)X_COORDINATE_OF_CAR + WIDTH_OF_BUMPER, 
    (int)Y_COORDINATE_OF_CAR + HEIGHT_OF_BUMPER
);
Rectangle otherCarBoundingBox = new Rectangle( \* x, y, ... *\ );
bool carIsTouchingBumper = otherCarBoundingBox.Intersects(bumperBoundingBox);
```

This may not be perfectly perfect, as in the parameters for rectangle might be in a different order or something like that. But once you have it, you can use `carIsTouchingBumper` and do stuff.

If you want the bumper to be a separate image, you could do the same thing as above, except use the coordinates of the bumper instead. Also you would have to make the bumper follow the car.